# Truffle and Remix compiles differently

Tags: truffle, remix, solc

I have a smart contract that outputs a different bytecode when compiled with truffle, and with remix, even though both seem to use the same compiler version: 0.5.7+commit.6da8b019 Is that a known issue ? Is that normal ?

This causes issues to verify my smart contract on etherscan, and thus to be trusted by my users, which is kind of a big deal.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, I've found the answer after digging a little bit more into remix's compilation option. It seems that right now, the default setting on remix is:

```
evmVersion: "petersburg"
```

Whereas on Truffle it is set to

```
evmVersion: "byzantium"
```

Setting explicitely byzantium in truffle-config fixed the bytecode, and it's now exactly the same as remix's bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

By default Truffle compiles with enabled optimizations, and Remix with disabled.

Comment: It shouldn't optimize, in my truffle's compilation result, it says "optimizer":{"enabled":false,"runs":200}
I wonder why the "runs" is here though, if optimizer is disabled